# About PHP IMAP and connections limit

Tags: php, imap, imap-open

I made an online CRM for our company that checks the imap accounts using php imap library.

I open the connections using imap_open

it works perfectly but sometimes I get an error in the line where imap_open is.

I get   [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)

I thought it was because I had some error where I did not closed the imap connection correctly, but after fixing everything I realized it was because the shared hosting from hostgator that I am using have a limit of 30 max imap connections per hour per IP.

the php code is on the same server that the imap server, is the same domain.

How can I solve this?? is strange that the hosting has a webmail (SmarterMail Enterprise 14.4) and the webmail don't get a conection error, I can open and close emails there all the time and don't get any errors.

Also is strange that while they have me blocked I can send emails using swiftmailer, maybe because sending an email doesn't have to do with opening an imap connection?

Comment: Outgoing emails use SMTP.  The webmail component does not necessarily use IMAP.

Comment: So there is no work arround for this?

Comment: use connection pooling?  Use some other technology that doesn't involve rebuilding the IMAP connection every few seconds?

Comment: I have to rebuildit because this is running on a shared hosting, so I have a max run time for php scripts, I have to close the conection before the timeout. Could you elaborate on conection pooling???

Comment: I don't know if you can do it with PHP; basically, saving connections in a cache to be reused.  IMAP connections really only work in one of two ways: 1) long lived while the user is connected, fetching information as the user needs or 2) synchronization: log in, pull all the state locally, only connect to resynchronize state.  Creating a connection to do one little thing is extremely hard on the server as it creates a new connection, new SSL, new authentication for every operation you do, hence the rate limit.